How can I uninstall EPPlus?
I just installed EPPlus, but now my entire website has crashed and I'm getting this error:
Method not found: 'System.IO.MemoryStream Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream()'.

I uninstalled EPPlus packages, but I'm still getting there error. Now things are getting hung up when I try to uninstall Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream. It keeps referencing index.d.ts having errors, but I don't know where this file is.
I've tried uninstalling all EPPlus packages in NuGet package manager, and Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream. However, Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream gets hung up on the index.d.ts.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

"having errors" and "hung up" doesn't give anyone much to go on. Provide the full errors (in code fences as I edited your error to be in, with lang-none language hint) and someone might be able to help.

Why don't you open explorer and search for: index.d.ts (as a start)?

If a project gets really messed up: Create a new project from scratch, then copy all the code files and paste them into the new project, I have have done that a few times, it really clears things up.

I would try clearing all the dlls from your bin folder and rebuilding.

Just curious cause I don't want to break things any further. What do you mean by "clearing all the dlls"?

I resolved the issue by downgrading Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream from 3.0.1 to 2.2.1.
To resolve this issue, I went to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, found the Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream install, and installed version 2.2.1 for the project and solution.
